# Retaining shape of a label with Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm creating my labels with semantic ui and been using the code mentioned below to generate tag labels

```
import React from 'react'
import { Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'
const color = '#009ce0';

const LabelExampleTag = () => (
  <div>
    <Label as='a' style={{ backgroundColor: `${color}` }}  tag>
      Featured
    </Label>
  </div>
)

export default LabelExampleTag
```

This will end up with a label like this
[image]

Now I want this label to be coloured around border of the shape and text and don't want the color in the background.
When I tried to add a basic to the class from semantic ui, it broken the shape.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Label } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const LabelExampleTag = () => (
  <div>
    <Label as='a' color='teal' basic  tag>
      Featured
    </Label>
  </div>
)

export default LabelExampleTag
```

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this with css or by tweaking something in the class?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue with the `semantic-ui`

As a workaround, you can try with the below styles.

```
.ui.basic::before {
  border-top: 1px solid #009c95 !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #009c95 !important;
}
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-mkmzi?file=/style.css:0-110